# How can I call from my frontend docker nginx to my backend in nodeJs docker with docker swarmn

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I have 3 containers that I communicate with docker swarm, if I run my application with http and connect as http //domain.com everything works fine, but if I use https ( //www.domain.com) I can't communicate my frontend with the backend and I get the following error:

Ajax.js: 10 POST https //www.domain.com/Init net :: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
can someone help me solve my problem
and understand the mistake
Thank you

I leave my compose

```
version: '3'
services:
ssl:
       image: danieldent/nginx-ssl-proxy
       restart: always
       environment:
         UPSTREAM: myApp:8086
         SERVERNAME: dominio.com
       ports:
            - 80:80/tcp
            - 443:443/tcp
       depends_on:
            - myApp
       volumes:
            -  ./nginxAPP:/etc/letsencrypt
            -  ./nginxAPP:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro
 bdd:
     restart: always
     image: postgres:12
     ports:
          - 5432:5432/tcp  
     environment:
         POSTGRES_USER: user
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 12345
         POSTGRES_DB: miBDD
     volumes:
          - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
        - 9095:80/tcp
    environment:
       PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user
       PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 12345
       PROXY_X_FOR_COUNT: 3
       PROXY_X_PROTO_COUNT: 3
       PROXY_X_HOST_COUNT: 3
       PROXY_X_PORT_COUNT: 3
    volumes:
      - ./pgadminAplicattion:/var/lib/pgadmin
myApp:
   restart: always
   image: appImage 
   ports:    
         - 8086:8086
   depends_on:
       - bdd
   working_dir: /usr/myApp
   environment:
       CONFIG_PATH: ../configuation
   command: "node server.js"
```

Comment: While using https, are you using a legitimate ssl certificate or a self-sign certificate. I also faced similar issue earlier which turn out, is because of using a self-sign certificate.

Comment: The container https generate a certificate from letenscript, how can fix the error? I dont undertand. I am sung nodeJs in the backend

Answer (score 0):

add this EXTRANAMES: [www.dominio.com](http://www.dominio.com) to your environment

```
ssl:
       image: danieldent/nginx-ssl-proxy
       restart: always
       environment:
         UPSTREAM: myApp:8086
         SERVERNAME: dominio.com
         EXTRANAMES: www.dominio.com
       ports:
            - 80:80/tcp
            - 443:443/tcp
       depends_on:
            - myApp
       volumes:
            -  ./nginxAPP:/etc/letsencrypt
            -  ./nginxAPP:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro
```